# How to parseResult [JSONArray]?

Tags: android, json, arraylist

I am getting JSON data. How to use JSONArray when download & display image in GridView. How can I do acheive this? I refer [Download and Display Image in Android GridView](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/download-and-display-image-in-android-gridview). It is JSONObject.

here is my code.

```
private void parseResult(String result) {
    try {
        JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray posts = response.optJSONArray("posts");
        GridItem item;
        for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject post = posts.optJSONObject(i);
            item = new GridItem();
            JSONArray img = post.getJSONArray("img");
            if (null != attachments && attachments.length() > 0) {
                JSONObject attachment = attachments.getJSONObject(0);
                if (img!= null)
                    item.setImage(img.getString("url"));
            }
            mGridData.add(item);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

here is refer code,

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "count": 45,
  "count_total": 397,
  "pages": 9,
  "posts": [
    {
      "id": 12378,
      "url": "http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/speech-to-text-in-android",
    },
    {...},
    {...}
  ]
}
```

here is my JSON,

```
[
  {
    "id": "95",
    "name": "Cherry",
    "menu": [
      {
        "menu_id": "18",
        "img": "925dd3ad6d50fa5686a82af26515be5d.jpg"
      }
    ]
  },
  {...},
  {...}
]
```

Comment: oh, why you have to use JSONArray? you don't map your json string to java object?

Comment: How to solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code :

For refer code:

```
try{
    JSONObject  object = new JSONObject (result);
    JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("posts");
    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
         JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
         String id = object.getString("id");
         String img_url = object.getString("url");

         item = new GridItem();
          if (img_url!= null)
                   item.setImage(img_url);
            mGridData.add(item);
        }
     }
     catch (JSONException e){
           e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

For second JSON

```
 try{
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
         JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
         String id = object.getString("id");
         String name = object.getString("name");

         JSONArray menu = object.getJSONArray("menu");
         for(int j=0;j<menu.length();j++){
             JSONObject menu_object = menu.getJSONObject(j);
             String menu_id = menu_object.getString("menu_id");
             String image_url = menu_object.getString("img");
             item = new GridItem();
              if (image_url!= null)
                       item.setImage(image_url);
                mGridData.add(item);
            }
        }
     }
     catch (JSONException e){
           e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: **img.getString("url")** I change **image_url** but can't solve method getString

Comment: check the edit...and there is two JSON ? which JSON image url u want to parse?

Comment: org.json.JSONException: Index 0 out of range [0..0) image_url is null

Comment: I use For second JSON; i add GridItem item; before for loop.

Comment: **Log.i("hello",image_url);** **hello: 925dd3ad6d50fa5686a82af26515be5d.jpg** but it doesn't show in GridView. I think something wrong me another code . Thank you

Comment: your image url need to be valid..,you can use `picasso` to show image using URL...if the parsing problem solved mark the answer as `correct`

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution :

```
    try {
        JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);

        JSONArray menu = response.optJSONArray("menu");

        GridItem item;

        for (int i = 0; i < menu.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject post = menu.optJSONObject(i);

            String menu_id=post.getString("menu_id");

            String img=post.getString("img");


            item = new GridItem();

            item.setImage(img);


            mGridData.add(item);

        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use google-gson library [link](https://github.com/google/gson)

Example JSON String

```
{
  "title": "Free Music Archive - Albums",
  "message": "",
  "errors": [],
  "total": "11259",
  "total_pages": 2252,
  "page": 1,
  "limit": "5",
  "dataset": [
    {
      "album_id": "7596",
      "album_title": "Album 1",
      "images": [
        {
          "image_id": "1",
          "user_id": null
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Albums.java**

```
class Albums {
    public String title;
    public String message;
    public List<string> errors = new ArrayList<string>();
    public String total;
    public int total_pages;
    public int page;
    public String limit;
    List<dataset> dataset = new ArrayList<dataset>();
}
```

**Main Class**

```
Albums albums = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Albums.class);
```

[Reference](http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-google-json-parse-json-to-java/)